# How can I load Windows 7 after I installed Mint 12 KDE?

Tags: windows-7, linux, linux-mint

I have Windows 7 installed. I attempted to install Mint side by side. Though, when I choose Windows from the Grub loader(knowing that Windows needs MBR) nothing happens. What is the best way to recover Windows 7. I have a Windows Recovery Essentials disk from Neosmart Tech. Yet, I am having trouble finding the correct method of erasing Linux Grub so that I may use the MBR.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, turning to the Ubuntu help forums can be of assistance.  One of the first things you can try, if you can still boot to Linux Mint, is installing [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

> launch Boot-Repair from either :
>
> - System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Gnome)
> - by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal
>
> Then try "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

This could easily take care of repairing the Windows MBR (the tool is for fixing a multitude of issues), or you could examine the page I linked to for images of the advanced options if you want to see what possibilities are open to you before you install it.

Of course, you could also choose to boot to your Windows 7 installation disc, and choose the "Repair your computer" option, then after it fixes the MBR, go ahead and boot normally to Windows.  Of course, you wouldn't have the dual boot option for the moment, but you could then install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to rebuild the dual boot menu.